Pandas shift operation with condition
Below I have a small dataset with 3 columns, ID; tag and value. Tag represent the source of the information that the feature 'value' is based on.
I want to create a lag feature for 'value'. Below I do that in an easy way. However, for index 3 and 4 we can see that 'tag' has the same value. This situation I do not want.
I wish to take 'tag' into consideration. I want a condition that to perform the shift only when 'tag' feature is not the same.
What would be good method to perform this?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2, 2,2,3,3,3],
              'tag':[10, 11, 15, 11, 12, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18],
             'value':[21, 19, 22, 41, 43, 43, 38, 9, 12, 16]})

df['value_lag'] = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'tag']).groupby('ID')['value'].shift(1)

print(df)

     ID  tag  value  value_lag
0   1   10     21        NaN
1   1   11     19       21.0
2   1   15     22       19.0
3   2   11     41        NaN
4   2   12     43       41.0
5   2   12     43       43.0
6   2   13     38       43.0
7   3   16      9        NaN
8   3   17     12        9.0
9   3   18     16       12.0

Desired output would be:
   ID  tag  value  value_lag
0   1   10     21        NaN
1   1   11     19       21.0
2   1   15     22       19.0
3   2   11     41        NaN
4   2   12     43       41.0
5   2   12     43       41.0 -Here, should not be 43 
6   2   13     38       43.0
7   3   16      9        NaN
8   3   17     12        9.0
9   3   18     16       12.0


What is your desired output?

Made amendments to the question, thanks for pointing it out.

You can remove duplicates, create MultiIndex, then use DataFrameGroupBy.shift and join shifted Series to original by DataFrame.join:
df = df.join(df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'tag'])
               .drop_duplicates(['ID','tag'])
               .set_index(['ID','tag'])
               .groupby('ID')['value'].shift().rename('value_lag'), on=['ID','tag']) 

print(df)
   ID  tag  value  value_lag
0   1   10     21        NaN
1   1   11     19       21.0
2   1   15     22       19.0
3   2   11     41        NaN
4   2   12     43       41.0
5   2   12     43       41.0
6   2   13     38       43.0
7   3   16      9        NaN
8   3   17     12        9.0
9   3   18     16       12.0


@jezraelThanks, very efficient solution.
